# Rendering Component with SolidJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, solid-js, google-books-api

I'm Trying to render a component called BookInfo that will contain certain informations about the book the user searched for. But when i try to access this route, the BookInfo content is displayed in the end of the page.

For example, my component BookInfo contains a text that says "Test" and when i access this component the text will be displayed in the below the cards component (I want only the BookInfo content to be displayed after i access its route).

BookInfo.jsx

```
function BookInfo() {
    return (
      <div>
      <h1>Test</h1>
      </div>
    );
}export default BookInfo;
```

```
SearchBooks.jsx

import axios from "axios";
import { createSignal } from "solid-js";
import { Routes, Route } from "@solidjs/router";
import BookInfo from "./BookInfo";

function SearchBooks() {
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = createSignal("");
  const [books, setBook] = createSignal([]);
  console.log(books)
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${searchText()}`
      );
      if (response) {
        const books = response.data.items;
        console.log(books);
        setBook(books);
        
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  return (
      <div className="w-full mt-10 bg-gray-100 flex flex-col items-center">
        <div className="container mx-auto dark:bg-gray-900 rounded-lg p-14">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <h1 className="text-center font-bold text-white text-4xl">
            Find your perfect books{" "}
          </h1>{" "}
          <br />
          <div className="sm:flex items-center bg-white rounded-lg overflow-hidden px-2 py-1 justify-between">
            <input
              className="text-base text-gray-400 flex-grow outline-none px-2"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Search for books"
              value={searchText()}
              onInput={(e) => setSearchText(e.target.value)}
            />
            <div className="ms:flex items-center px-2 rounded-lg space-x-4 mx-auto ">
              <button className="dark:bg-gray-900 text-white text-base rounded-lg px-4 py-2 font-thin">
                Search
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-center gap-4 p-4">
          {books().map((book) => (
            <Book book={book} />
          ))}
        </div>
        <style>
        {`
          .flex {
            display: flex;
          }

          .flex-wrap {
            flex-wrap: wrap;
          }

          .justify-center {
            justify-content: center;
          }

          .gap-4 > * + * {
            margin-left: 1rem;
          }

          .p-4 {
            padding: 1rem;
          }
        `}
      </style>
    </div>
    );
}

function Book(props) {
  const { id } = props.book;
  const { title } = props.book.volumeInfo;
  const  authors  = [props.book.volumeInfo.authors];
  const linkTo = {
    pathname: `/searched-books/${id}`,
    state: { bookData: props.book },
  };
  return (
    <div class="max-w-sm bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-lg shadow dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
    <a href="#">
        <img class="rounded-t-lg" src="/docs/images/blog/image-1.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
    <div class="p-5">
        <a href="#">
            <h5 class="mb-2 text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 dark:text-white">{title}</h5>
        </a>
        <p class="mb-3 font-normal text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">{authors.join(", ")}</p>
        <a href="#" class="inline-flex items-center px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-center text-white bg-blue-700 rounded-lg hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800">
            Read more
            <svg aria-hidden="true" class="w-4 h-4 ml-2 -mr-1" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10.293 3.293a1 1 0 011.414 0l6 6a1 1 0 010 1.414l-6 6a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L14.586 11H3a1 1 0 110-2h11.586l-4.293-4.293a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
  );
}

export default SearchBooks;
```

```
app.jsx


import Header from '/components/Header'
import SearchBooks from '/components/SearchBooks'
import BookInfo from '/components/BookInfo'
import AboutInfo from '/components/AboutInfo'
import Tips from '/components/Tips'
import Cards from '/components/Cards'
import {Route, Routes} from '@solidjs/router';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <Header />
    <SearchBooks />
    <AboutInfo />
    <Tips />
    <Cards />
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/book" component={BookInfo} />
    </Routes>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
index.jsx

/* @refresh reload */
import { render } from 'solid-js/web';
import {Router} from '@solidjs/router';

import './index.css';
import App from './App';
const root = document.getElementById('root');


render(() => (
    <Router>
        <App/>
    </Router>
),root);
```

Comment: In your app component, SearchBooks is above the router, so it's always displayed, regardless of the url/route. You probably want it to be a route instead, just like BookInfo